# Connecting Arduino to internet through HC-06 and then smartphone

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

Can I use HC-06 to connect the Arduino to a smartphone (which I am already doing) and thereafter take the data to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in quite the way you think.

In this case the smartphone is acting exactly like the PC when you have the Arduino plugged in to it. You have a serial connection. Theoretically you can:

- Send a request to the smartphone over the serial bluetooth connection
- Write some software on the smartphone to interpret that request and perform some action depending on what the request is

That way the smartphone is then acting like an incredibly expensive and bulky ESP8266.

Comment: Is there an app that can perform this action for me like receiving the bluetooth serial data like 'blueterm' does and sends the data on some condition?

Comment: I am not aware of one. There may be one though. You will have to search Play.

Answer (score 0):

old thread I know..

You can use MIT App Inventor to write/make an app for your Android phone.

This will do several things:

- pair with your Arduino/BT device.
- take data sent from the Arduino/BT device and parse it
- do what you like with that data at that point, save to a database..etc. send info to a map (like google maps)..etc

You havent stated what you want to do with the data after it reaches the phone.

Alternately.. you may be able to get rid of the BT device.. and use an ESP8266 wi-fi module and connect directly to a 3rd party web script/service and dump the data directly to the 'internet'